# TypeError: cron.CronJob is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make the bot writing messages every day.
I installed npm install discord.js and npm install --save node-cron.

```
const { Client, Intents, GuildMember } = require('discord.js');
var cron = require('node-cron');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const TOKEN = '#';

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log("I am ready");
});

let job = new cron.CronJob('30 2 * * *', () => {
client.channels.cache.get('#').send("Hello!!")
})
job.start();
client.login(TOKEN)
```

And terminal says

```
 "let job = new cron.CronJob('30 2 * * *', () => {
      ^
 TypeError: cron.CronJob is not a constructor"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `node-cron`?

Comment: It seems you're mixing things: [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) vs [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Answer (score 0):

As @Zsolt Meszaros has mentioned, you're mixing [`cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). If you want to use `node-cron`, your scheduling should look something like this:

```js
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

Applied into your code it would look something like this:

```
const { Client, Intents, GuildMember } = require("discord.js");
const cron = require("node-cron");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
const TOKEN = "#";

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready");
});

let job = cron.schedule("30 2 * * *", () => {
  client.channels.cache.get("#").send("Hello!!");
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

**NOTE**

You do not need to use `task.start()` unless you provide the `scheduled: false` parameter into the task.